# Wifi not connecting (ASUS N76VZ + Intel centrino 2230 + Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: 13.10, asus, intel-wireless

i have recently installed ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 8.1. The wifi is detecting the other wifi devices but when i try to connect, it goes on and on and then it doesn' connect. I have tried the additional drivers but nothing appears in that list. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with an Acer Aspire (4339-2618) on multiple versions of Ubuntu. While I haven't fully diagnosed the problem, I have found a very stable work-around that you might try. The problem turned out to only occur when I used the native `network-manager`. That is what you use to find your local wifi networks in your window manager, it is installed by default on Ubuntu.

After attempting multiple variation on driver/kernel fixes, I turned off `network-manager` and used `wpa_supplicant` which should be installed by default, or otherwise can be installed with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

This assumes that the wifi network you are trying to connect with is using wpa (most are). If you know your wifi network and password, you should run the following command:

```
wpa_passphrase mynetwork mypassword
```

That will output something like this:

```
network={
    ssid="mynetwork"
    #psk="mypassword"
    psk=69e49214ef4e7e23d0ece077c2faf3c73f7522ad52a26b33527fa78d9033ff35
}
```

You should delete the #psk line, as that presents your password in plaintext in a config file and is not a very secure practice (the psk hash itself isn't so great to have in a config file, but that's [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927347/does-wpa-passphrase-use-a-hashing-algorithm)).

Copy that output and paste it at the bottom of the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

You will only have to do this once. If you want to add additional networks, you can re-run the `wpa_passphrase` commands with those network names and passwords and paste those into the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

The final steps are to disable `network-manager` and run `wpa_supplicant`. I put this all in a bash script called run_wifi.sh and run the script as sudo from the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
service network-manager stop  # stop network manager
killall wpa_supplicant        # exit any running wpa_supplicants
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient wlan0                # get ip address from router
```

Here it is assumed that your wireless network shows up as wlan0 when you type `ifconfig`, you may have to change that to `wlan1` or whatever the case may be.

Make this script executable (`chmod +x ./run_wifi.sh`) and run it with the line:

```
sudo ./run_wifi.sh
```

After the next reboot, you can simply use the previous line to connect to your network. If you want to connect to the ethernet port using network manager again, you can turn it back on `service network-manager start` or simply run `sudo dhclient eth0`.

If this doesn't work for you, please let me know and I will delete this answer.